# Is it possible to share the forms authentication cookie across two asp.net applications that live on the same domain name?

Tags: iis, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

As you can see below, I have set up my three different web applications under a single IIS entry.
The root application is accessible without the need to authenticate.

WebApp1 and WebApp2 need to be secure and only accessible after logging in. 
if I add forms authentication to WebApp2 it forces me to login once again even after successful login on WebApp1.

I would also like to redirect the login screen of WebApp1 if WebApp2 is accessed directly.

```
-->Root App
     |
     -------->WebApp1 (Administration asp.net web app) secure access only
     |           |
 web.config      -------->WebApp2 (Child mvc4 app) secure access only
     |           |           |
     |       web.config      |
     |           |           |
     |           |       web.config
     |           |           |
     |           |           |
```

Comment: Looks like my approach worked by duplicating the membership / role / authentication sections from WebApp1 and Webapp2 web.config file.
I was also able to redirect to the WebApp1 login.aspx page when accessing WebApp2 application directly (without logging in first) by simply adding "../login.aspx" to the loginUrl attribute in the authentication element.
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".myAuthCookie" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="../login.aspx" timeout="20" ...... />
</authentication>